# I got stuck a SQL Join and Count

Tags: mysql, sql

i write a Query like this

```
SELECT COUNT(NameEN)as [DISTRICT] FROM [OTOP].[Custom].[tblRefProvince]
SELECT [OTOP].[Custom].[tblRefProvince].NameEN,[OTOP].[Custom].[tblRefDistrict].NameDefault
FROM [OTOP].[Custom].[tblRefProvince]
INNER JOIN [OTOP].[Custom].[tblRefDistrict]
ON [OTOP].[Custom].[tblRefProvince].ID =[OTOP].[Custom].[tblRefDistrict].ProvinceID
```

it is show

```
| DISTRICT |
    xxx
------------------------
NameEN | NameDefault |
  xxx         xxxx
-----------------------
```

i need this to show

```
NameEN | NameDefault | DISTRICT |
```

in one table,how can i solve this

thank you for your help

Comment: Please change the title of the question. its not informative

Comment: you are firing two queries... without combining them.. thats why you are getting result like this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first query seems to be counting the number of rows in `tblRefProvince`.

You can include this in the other query by using a subquery:

```
select rp.NameEN, rd.NameDefault,
       (select COUNT(NameEN)
        from [OTOP].[Custom].[tblRefProvince]
       ) as district
from [OTOP].[Custom].[tblRefProvince] rp inner join
     [OTOP].[Custom].[tblRefDistrict] rd
     on rp.ID = rd.ProvinceID;
```

Note that I also introduced table aliases so the query is more readable.